# What are Complex Types in Context with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, complextype

Right now I am learning a lot about the Entity Framework from Videos on Pluralsight, so excuse my Question which might look newbish but I can not understand what Complex Types are or why I would need them.

I do know that  I have to map them via Annotations or Fluent Api something like this:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<blubb>();
```

Maybe someone could elaborate the need of Complex Types for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume you have an entity for Courses in a class, that entity has scalar properties of Location, Days and Time, but you find you want to abstract that so that other entities can use the same model.  So you can create a complex type that contains Days, Location and Time give it a name: ComplexType1.  Now other entities can use this type rather than individual scalar properties just by declaring ComplexType1 in the model definition.

Comment: Thanks for the good Answer. In the tutorial it wasn't mentioned that I can use this complex type for more than one Entity, that's why I didn't know how it should be useful at all :)

Comment: Upvote for pointing out that other entities can use the model too.

Answer (score 6):

Complex Types are repeating structural patterns in your database.  You have to custom map them because there is no way for it to be inferred.

An example would be two tables that both have address related columns:

**Company**

```
CompanyName
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
Postcode
```

**Account Manager**

```
Name
TelephoneNumber
SuperiorName
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
Postcode
```

This is obviously not well-normalized database design but such situations do occur.  You can abstract the model for address into a complex type, then specify that both Company and AccountManager have that complex type rather than keep mapping the matching (albeit separate in the database) columns for each table that has address columns.

Here's an in depth article on Complex Types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj680147.aspx

And here is one that isn't quite so heavy, and shows the benefit of mapping two addresses on one model, things like that: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Complex type are types that don't map to a table like entities instead they map to one or more fields.

The following complex type

```
public class Descriptor
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

And entity

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Descriptor { get;set;}
}
```

This would map to a table with `Name` and `Description` fields. It is a useful way to have a type encapsulate a common set of fields/properties you might want on several entities.

Comment: The MYEntity class example is wrong as it doesn't refer to any known Complex type.