# Entity Framework - store data of SubClass in same datatable as the data of the MainClass

Tags: entity-framework

With the .Net Entity Framework I would like to store the data of a "SubClass" in the same datatable as the data of the "MainClass". SubClass has no Id, its just for reusablity that I want to create a Class a part from the MainClass.

```
public class MainClass
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public SubClass Property1 { get; set; }
    }

public class SubClass
    {
    //This class has no Id and its data should be stored in the same table as the data of MainClass
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Look for inheritance pattern TPH.

Comment: Hi Gert, thanks for your help. What I am looking for is a solution without inheritance as the SubClass is not derived from the MainClass. I did not choose the names well ...

Comment: Ok, you're looking for [complex types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27382080/861716) then.

Comment: Hey Gert, complex types are definetly what I was looking for ! Thanks a lot !
How could I mark your comment as the answer to my question ? Or could you post an answer so that I could mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you're looking for complex types then. – Gert Arnold Apr 20 at 19:58

Answer (score 0):

This should take you in the right direction. You have to inherit from the MainClass and make sure that both classes are mapped to the same table in database. I'm not sure why you want the SubClass to be a property of mainclass, if that was intentional or if you just where unsure of how inheritance works...

```
[Table("MainClassTableName")]
public class MainClass
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
    }

[Table("MainClassTableName")]
public class SubClass : MainClass
    {
    //This class has no Id and its data should be stored in the same table as the data of MainClass
       public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: No problem @Fabianus, just mark my answer as resolved and I'm happy :)

Comment: Excuse me - I fact my comment was posted to quick ...
I do not want the SubClass to inherit from the MainClass. Here ist an example of possible use: imagin a "Quantity" Class with a property "number" and a property "unit". This class should be usable in various places. But yet I do not want it to have an id as I want the quantities to be stored in the table of the actual MainClass. You see ?